# Right size in Unity : image + scale or image -> svg -> blender -> Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, inkscape

I'm new to unity, and I'm trying to make a 3D game about handball (European sport).

First, I created a field, then I put a real field image (png) as a texture. The field was scaled to match a real handball field. OK, looks good.

Then I had to deal with what I would further refer to as the key (free throw lane) : I imported the image in Inkscape, got a .svg, then imported it in blender, extruded it, and finally imported it in unity.

Here is my problem : when I scale the 3D key to match the width of the texture image, the length of the 3D model doesn't match (by roughly 1/3) the length of the texture (I can provide a screenshot if needed). And I wish to have real dimensions...

Where am I wrong ? Where is the error ?

Thanks in advance for your advices, and sorry for my english (I'm french)

PS: please inform me if I make any english mistakes.

Comment: Did you reset your model scale in Blender before exporting it? (apply scale)

Comment: Nope, I'm new to Blender too...

Comment: Then that's probably what's causing the problem. Whenever you do single-axis scaling, you need to Apply Scale (so it becomes 1, 1, 1 again, but the object stays the same) and export it like that.

Comment: I didn't do any single-axis scaling, but I will try it when I can, thanks !